# Default parallelism with Dynamic Allocation in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am launching Spark application with dynamicAllocation enabled. I set the `initialExecutors` to be 10. Each executor has 4 cores. I set the `maxExecutors` to 80.

As per my understanding when the spark context starts it checks the number of vCores available to set the `spark.default.parallelism`. So in this case the `default.parallelism` will be set to 40 (10x4). But my job has the capacity to scale it to 320 (80x4).

My question is how does dynamicAllocation deal with default.parallelism? Why it does not take into consideration the max capacity? What I have noticed is that reading the data from HDFS runs slow for the same job when I set the above-mentioned configuration. But when I set the `initialExecutors` to a higher value (60) read works faster. Why dynamicAllocation does not handle this automatically?

```
Spark Version 3.2.0
Cluster manager Yarn
```